# running multiple R scripts in bash script

Tags: r, bash, shell

I have 2 R scripts called `script1.R` and `script2.R` respectively and I want to run them sequentially as pipeline. To do so, I am trying a bash script to run 2 R scripts, use inputs and arguments (for every script) and returns output (for every script). since there are 2 R scripts, we have 2 steps as follows:
1- this the command for the 1st R script:

```
Rscript script1.R /path/to/input /path/to/OutputDir argument1 argument2
```

2- this the command for the 2nd R script:

```
Rscript script2.R /path/to/output_of_1st_script /path/to/OutputDir argument3 default_yes
```

to run these 2 R scripts I have made the following bash script but does not return anything! do you know how to fix it?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e;
set -u;


OUTDIR1="./output1/";
OUTDIR2="./output2/";
INDIR="./input/";

argument1=$1;
argument2=$2;
argument3=$3;

mkdir ${OUTDIR1} || true;
#to run the 1st script
ls -1 ${INDIR}/*/inputfile.txt | sort -V | while read infile; do
    b=$(basename $(dirname "$infile"));

    ./script1.R \
        -v \
        run \
        -o "${of}" \
        -f 0 \
        argument1 \
        argument2 \
        "${b},${infile}" \
    ;
done

#to run the 2nd script. input of this sript is the output from previous script
ls -1 ${OUTDIR1}/*/output.txt | sort -V | while read outfile1; do
    b=$(basename $(dirname "$outfile1"));

    ./script1.R \
        -v \
        run \
        -o "${of}" \
        -f 0 \
        argument3 \
        "${b},${outfile1}" \
    ;
done
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with shell script, but I don't see a definition for `of` in either loop. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Also, in the second loop, the called script should probably be `./script2.R.py` or `Rscript script2.R`. Either case, the command line that you explained us that have to be used and the command line you actually used are different.

Comment: BTW, what are you expecting to be returned by the script?

Comment: @ Poshi: this script will return an output directory containing the results of those 2 R scripts.